# Compiling the icu sqlite extension statically linked to icu

Tags: sqlite, icu

I want to compile the [icu sqlite extension](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/getfile?f=sqlite/ext/icu/README.txt) statically linked to [icu](http://icu-project.org).

This is what I've tried, maybe the mistake is obvious to you.

```
> cd icu/source
> ./runConfigureIcu Linux --enable-static --with-packaging-format=archive
...
> make

> cd ../../icu-sqlite
> gcc -o libSqliteIcu.so -shared icu.c -I../icu/source/common
      -I../icu/source/i18n -L ../icu/source/lib -lsicuuc -lsicui18n -lsicudata
...
> sqlite3
> .load "libSqliteIcu.so"
Undefined symbol utf8_countTrailBytes
```

### Files

#### icu sqlite extension

[Download icu.c from sqlite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/getfile?f=sqlite/ext/icu/icu.c)

#### ICU 4.2.1

[Download ICU4C from icu-project.org](http://icu-project.org/download/4.2.html#ICU4C)

### My Requirements

- Runs on Linux & Windows
- Only one file that I have to distribute: `libSqliteIcu.so`.

Any idea what else I can try?

### Documentation

- [Sqlite ICU extension's readme](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/getfile?f=sqlite/ext/icu/README.txt)
- [ICU's readme](http://icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/trunk/readme.html)

Comment: Hi gs, If you success compile and load icu module in sqlite3 in windows, would you mind sharing which compiler you use like (vc++/mingw,cygwin) and steps how you compile it? I can compile on linux with no problem, but still no success on windows yet.

Comment: I would like to see a solution for windows too. Could someone provide the necessary steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command line worked for me on Linux:

```
g++ -shared --language c  -o libSqliteIcu.so icu.c  -I../icu/source/common -I../icu/source/i18n -lpthread -lm   -L../icu/source/lib -lsicui18n -lsicuuc -lsicudata  -lpthread -lm
```

Notice the ordering of the library files, and the use of g++  to make sure the c++ runtime is referenced even though we're compiling a C file.

NB.
I used the output of `icu-config --prefix=../icu/source --ldflags`.

Comment: The important difference seems to be that you used g++ instead of gcc. I'll try it in windows and then award you the bounty if it works.

Comment: Haven't found the time to test it yet, still, I'm awarding you the bounty because it works for Linux.

Comment: For anyone arriving through searching, this worked on Windows for me: gcc -shared icu.c -L C:\msys64\mingw64\lib -licuin -licuuc -licudt -lpthread -lm -o icu.dll, where icu-config --ldflags gave -L/mingw64/lib -licuin -licuuc -licudt.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem as you. You can edit icu\include\utf8.h and replace following lines

```
          #ifdef U_UTF8_IMPL
          U_EXPORT const uint8_t 
          #elif defined(U_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION) || defined(U_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION)
          U_CFUNC const uint8_t
          #else
          U_CFUNC U_IMPORT const uint8_t /* U_IMPORT2? */ /*U_IMPORT*/ 
          #endif
          utf8_countTrailBytes[256];
```

with

```
              const uint8_t countTrailBytes[256];
```

This should do the trick.