# Building sqlite - System.Data.SQLite wih ICU extension

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite, icu

I need to manually build [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) (which is an ADO.NET adapter for SQLite) and I need to include ICU extension for sqlite because I have need for case insensitive searches.

I have sqlite-netFx-source-1.0.84.0 source, current source can be downloaded from [link](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki).

How can I do this? I didnt find any answer yet, the most closely was answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818678/compiling-the-icu-sqlite-extension-statically-linked-to-icu), but I need icu for System.Data.SQLite and I need to be able to manually build everything.

Also, if this what I need is possible, will I be able to execute case insensitive `WHERE field LIKE` queries in SQL for existing, non FTS tables? Or ICU extension just work for FTS tables?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found probably better solution for my problem - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10361892/1460830