# SQLite with ICU [compile]

Tags: android, sqlite, android-ndk, icu

I'm working on a android application with SQLite, but I have a problem with charterers not ASCII. I researched about that and I found the solution is compile a new SQLite version with ICU activated. 
I downloaded the NDK, ICU and I follow the guide of this page:

http://www.sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

However this page only shows how to compile the a new SQLite, I do not how to add ICU on this process.

How can I compile the SQLite with ICU ? (I'm using Windows)

Thanks.

Comment: `I have a problem with charterers not ASCII` what problem? SQLite on android uses UTF-8 by default.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818678/compiling-the-icu-sqlite-extension-statically-linked-to-icu

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried myself yet but to my understanding adding -DSQLITE_ENABLE_ICU as a compile parameter should do it.